# Installing HHVM "The following packages have unmet dependencies"

Tags: 12.04, apt, boost

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hhvm : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.49.0 but it is not installable
        Depends: libboost-program-options1.49.0 but it is not installable
        Depends: libboost-system1.49.0 but it is not installable
        Depends: libboost-regex1.49.0 but it is not installable
        Depends: libboost-thread1.49.0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: I encountered the same problem in Ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I have forgotten to isntall Boost: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-Ubuntu-12.04#installing-boost-149

Comment: Glad you sorted it out, and thanks for reporting back. Please accept your own answer with the tick on the left.